# Full table scan on JOIN table using PK

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a bit puzzled on why a full table scan is performed on a simple sql query that uses primary key to join:

```
SELECT max(pd.cre_dt)
FROM D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
JOIN D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE br
ON pd.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID = br.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID
AND br.BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID IN (2217, 2237, 2257);
```

Explain shows:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                           |     1 |    24 |       |   283K  (2)| 00:00:15 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                        |                           |     1 |    24 |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                            |                           |   677K|    15M|    14M|   283K  (2)| 00:00:15 |
|   3 |    INLIST ITERATOR                     |                           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE     |   694K|  6779K|       | 17430   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE_IF4 |   694K|       |       |  1469   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT        |  9567K|   127M|       |   260K  (1)| 00:00:14 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where `pd.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID` is a primary key.
Despite millions of records, I wouldn't expect this query to be slow.
What is the reason, and how to improve?

Comment: What is the size of `ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT` in bytes and what is the clustering factor of PK index? This may be due to not very good selectivity of index access, so large amount of data will be read even via index.

Answer (score 3):

Does this give you a different plan?

```
SELECT max(pd.cre_dt)
FROM D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
JOIN D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE br
                ON pd.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID = br.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID
WHERE br.BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID IN (2217, 2237, 2257);
```

If so then you want to add BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID to your index.

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply. This gives me the same plan. BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID has an index, and this query on its own (without the join) performs very well.

Comment: @html_programmer you need an index on the combination of the two columns... having two indexes on the columns won't help speed up this query.

Answer (score 1):

Probably last time statistics for `ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT` were calculated when there were very few rows, so Oracle thinks that hash will be very small. Either try recalculating statistics or use hints:

```
SELECT /*+ leading(br pd) use_nl(pd)*/ max(pd.cre_dt)
FROM D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT pd
JOIN D00ZVZ01.ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE br
ON pd.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID = br.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID
AND br.BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID IN (2217, 2237, 2257);
```

Comment: `USE_NL` for 690k rows is unlikely to be performance improvement. 15mb hash size is not very large

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didn't increase the retrieval speed.

Answer (score 1):

The optimiser estimates that it will access 694K rows from ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE for the three BRIEF_REG_GROEP_ID values, using an index, and then it needs to get the corresponding details from ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT. 694K individual index lookups is a lot (consider that it has to go the the index for each one and then use the rowid to access the table, in a loop, 694K times), and it has calculated that it will take less effort to just read ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT once and crunch the two sets in a single hash join. Index lookups are usually better for small volumes of data.

Is it any faster if you hint it to use the index?

Are the row estimates in the execution plan correct? How many rows are there in each table and how many will you actually read?

What is your Oracle version and do you have adaptive features enabled?

It's slightly odd that your query has no `WHERE` clause but instead a filtering condition is included in the inner join. I expect the optimiser will rewrite it as a `WHERE` predicate anyway, but I would still want to experiment to see whether it affected the plan.

Comment: Hello, I checked the number of rows and they are correct. I.e. 694k rows from the WHERE ... IN clause on ZVZ_BRIEF_REGISTRATIE (without the join) and 956k rows from the ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT. I tried to add WHERE clause instead of AND (on the join) but this gives indeed the same result. The problem is that they want a REST call to retrieve this status, but it will take too long and the browser might time out on an ajax request.

Comment: Actually the estimate is 9567K rows for ZVZ_PRINT_DOCUMENT, i.e. around 956M, of which it uses 677K, which is a little under 10%. Maybe 677K index lookups would be faster, maybe it wouldn't. That's why I wondered if it is actually any faster if you make it use the index with a hint.

Comment: Adding an index to the CRE_DT helped reduce from > 2m to about 24seconds. I tried different hint strategies but wasn't able to reduce it further. Thanks for advice, I think 24secs should be doable for internal use.

Comment: Is that one index on (PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID, CRE_DT)? That would save it having to visit the table at all.